# Thymeleaf th:text does not work in some case

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I started to work with thymeleaf in a basic project. When I want to display a message in the sign up page the th:text does not work. I used already th:text in other .html files and it works there but in the signUp.html doesn't.

**Here is my controller where I set the message:**

```
package com.teszt.thymeleaftest.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MemberController {

   MembersService membersService;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginPage(){

        return "/login/login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/signUp")
    public  String showSignUpPage(Model theModel){

        Members theMember = new Members();

        theModel.addAttribute("member", theMember);

        return "/login/signUp";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveMember(@ModelAttribute("member")  Members theMember, ModelMap modelMap){

        Members tempMember = membersService.findByEmail(theMember.getEmail());

        if(tempMember != null){
            modelMap.addAttribute("error", "Email is already exist!");
            return "redirect:/login/signUp";
        }else{
            membersService.save(theMember);

            //prevent duplication
            return "redirect:/login/login";
        }

    }

}
```

**Here is my signUp.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <title>Signup</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <h3>Signup</h3>
    <hr>

    <p class="h4 mb-4">Signup</p>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/login/save}" th:object="${member}" method="POST">

        <input type="text"  th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="First name">

        <input type="text"  th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Last name">

        <input type="text"  th:field="*{email}"  class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Email">

        <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="Password">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Save</button>

        <p th:text="${error}" />

    </form>

    <br>

    Do you have an account? <a th:href="@{/login/login}">Click here</a>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As I mentioned above this is the only html where the th:text does not works, everywhere else is good.

I hope somebody can help me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to take the [tour]. Also take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting answers is always completely optional (as is voting) - but I would recommended it, as it can help others to find good answers more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `redirect:`, you lose all your model attributes (because it's loading a new page).  You need to use a `FlashAttribute` instead.  Like this:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveMember(@ModelAttribute("member") Members theMember, ModelMap modelMap, RedirectAttributes redirAttrs){
    Members tempMember = membersService.findByEmail(theMember.getEmail());

    if(tempMember != null){
        redirAttrs.addFlashAttribute("error", "Email is already exist!");
        return "redirect:/login/signUp";
    }else{
        membersService.save(theMember);
        //prevent duplication
        return "redirect:/login/login";
    }
}
```