# Model attribute not visible by thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have this code which should be displaying the messages using Thymeleaf

```
if (!rooms.isEmpty()) {
    model.addAttribute("errorMessages", rooms);

    return "redirect:booking-form";
}
```

Instead, Thymeleaf is not able to resolve the model (it gets underlined in red).

It becomes visible when I add the below code but with no values.

```
@ModelAttribute("errorMessages")
public Map<String, String> msg() {
    return new HashMap<>();
}
```

How can I display the messages here?

```html
<div th:each="e : ${errorMessages.values()}"
     class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show"
     role="alert">
    <strong><span><i class='bx bx-calendar-exclamation bx-tada'></i></span></span></strong> <span th:text="${e}">Error</span>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
            aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/check-availability")
public String checkAvailability(@Valid BookingBindingModel bindingModel, BindingResult br,
                                RedirectAttributes rAtt, Model model,
                                @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser user) {
    if (br.hasErrors()) {
        rAtt
                .addFlashAttribute("bindingModel", bindingModel)
                .addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.bindingModel", br);
        return "redirect:booking-form";
    }

    CheckAvailabilityDto dto = this.mapper.map(bindingModel, CheckAvailabilityDto.class);
    Map<String, String> rooms = this.bookingService.checkAvailability(dto);

    if (!rooms.isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("errorMessages", rooms);

        return "redirect:booking-form";
    }
    return "redirect:/details";

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf th:text does not work in some case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68149717/thymeleaf-thtext-does-not-work-in-some-case)

Comment: No, because I have tried it as well and it does not work.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  Model attributes are not persisted across redirects, and I've used FlashAttributes before to solve this exact problem. Edit: you have multiple redirects... do you other flash attributes work? `bindingModel`?

Comment: The binding model which I use with flash attribute is visible because I have     @ModelAttribute("bindingModel") public BookingBindingModel bindingModel() {
return new BookingBindingModel(); } . I have tried adding rAtt.addFlashAttribute("errorMessages", rooms); I also tried with this line                    
 if (!model.containsAttribute("messages"))  but didn't work either. It is only visible with  @ModelAttribute("errorMessages") as in the example above but it is empty.

Comment: I got it working with this rAtt.addFlashAttribute("messages", roomMessages); and this  @ModelAttribute("messages") RoomMessages roomMessages